# Dropdown multiselect not showing when values set in javascript append

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-multiselect

I have a `multiselect` dropdown that shows options when I hard code them, but as soon as I get my values from the database and append them to the options it does not show. Is there another way to show these values?

Scripts:

```html
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js">
    </script>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"/>
</head>
```

Select dropdown which shows dropdown values:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <select class="form-control" id="multiselectpuc" multiple="multiple">
        @*<option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>*@
    </select>
</div>
```

Appending data to the dropdown:

```js
$('#multiselectstudent').multiselect({
    buttonWidth: '285px',
    allSelectedText: 'All',
    includeSelectAllOption: true,
    nonSelectedText: 'select puc',
});

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '@Url.Action("GetStudents", "Home")',
    datatdataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
        data.data.forEach(function (item) {
            console.log(item.id)
            //$('#multiselectstudent').append("<option value='" + item.id + "'>" + item.code+ "</option>");
            $("#multiselectstudent option[value='" + item.id + "']").prop("selected", true);
        });
});
```

`item.data` has values in console, I can also see the values set in the elements tab, but the dropdown does not show. Please see image:
[image]

Comment: `multiselectstudent` is not equal to `multiselectpuc`.

Comment: Hi @Teemu,changed the name accordingly it still does not work,got all my values in the element but only shows the hardcoded one and two,the problem is with the append and not element name

Comment: You *probably* need to reinitiate the bootstrap-multiselect after appending items.  There may be an API call to "rebuild" the UI, but probably just need to call `.multiselect` to rebuild it.

Comment: also tried  $('#multiselectpuc').multiselect('refresh'); after foreach but the appended values still dont appear,only hardcoded ones appear

Comment: From [the documentation](https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#methods) you would need `$('#multiselectpuc').multiselect('rebuild');`

Answer (score 2):

UI wrappers over a `<select>` will generally not update themselves when you change the underlying select and will need additional code.

In the case of [bootstrap-multiselect](/questions/tagged/bootstrap-multiselect), after changing the underlying `select` you need to call

```
$("#selectid").multiselect("rebuild");
```

> https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#getting-started
>
> Rebuilds the whole dropdown menu. All selected options will remain selected (if still existent!).

Comment: Thanks after appending data from DB i had to use $('#multiselectstudent').multiselect('rebuild'); after the loop to reload the dropdown with new values